# Corona SDK getting error when loading image from the system.DocumentsDirectory

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard, corona-director

I am trying to load image from the system.DocumentsDirectory but i get this error message.

```
WARNING: Failed to find image(C:\Users\beri\AppData\Roaming\Corona Labs\Corona S
imulator\Sandbox\jet shooter - pro-B1C630B0B5247780928E75EA15C69ABF\Documents\cu
stomJet.png)
```

I am using this code to create the image and display it again but i get the error message saying the image doesn't exist.

```
-- Creating the image 
local screenBounds =
 {
     xMin = 0,
     xMax = 800,
     yMin = 116.5,
     yMax = 360,
 }
 local customJet = display.captureBounds( screenBounds )
 local baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory;
 display.save( customJet, "customJet.png", baseDir)

-- Loading the image 
local path = system.pathForFile( "customJet.png", system.DocumentsDirectory )
local jetOne = display.newImage(path)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Creating the image 
local screenBounds =
 {
     xMin = 0,
     xMax = 800,
     yMin = 116.5,
     yMax = 360,
 }
 local customJet = display.captureBounds( screenBounds )
 local baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory;
 display.save( customJet, "customJet.png", baseDir)

-- Loading the image 
local jetOne = display.newImage( "customJet.png", system.DocumentsDirectory )
```

Comment: +1 but you should probably explain why: newImage expects filename to be relative to baseDir, with baseDir default is system.ResourceDir. In your case the png is in the documents folder so you must override as you show in your answer. Thanks for posting.